# $A(t)=\int_{0}^{t} I_{(X\geq u)} \,dΛ(u)$ is a predictable process

Tags: stochastic-processes, filtrations

I am currently reading the book "Counting Processes and Survival Analysis" by Fleming and Harrington and I am stuck in the proof of Proposition 1.4.2 p.34:

**Proposition 1.4.2:**

Let $(T,U)$ be a failure and censoring time respectively and let $X=min(T,U)$. If:

$Λ(t)=\int_{0}^{t} (1-F(u-))^{-1} \,dF(u)$, then the right continuous process:

$A(t)=\int_{0}^{t} I_{(X\geq u)} \,dΛ(u)$ is predictable with respect to the filtration defined as:

$ \mathcal{F_{t}}=$ σ{ $I_{(X\leq u,δ=0)}$ , $I_{(X\leq u, δ=1)}$: $0\leq u\leq t$}.

The predictable σ-algebra is defined as the set that is generated by all the rectangles of the form:

$\{{0}\}\times A, A\epsilon\mathcal{F_{0}}$ and $[a,b) \times A, 0<a\leq b\leq\infty$,
$A\epsilon\mathcal{F_{a-}}$

The proof starts by defining:

$A_{mn}(t)=(Λ(\frac{n+1}{2^{m}})-Λ(\frac{n}{2^{m}}))I_{(\frac{n}{2^{m}},\infty)}I_{(X\geq \frac{n}{2^{m}})}$

and

$A_{m}(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{mn}(t)$.

If $A_{mn}(t)$ is predictabe and $A_{m}(t)$ converges to $A$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$ then $A$ must be predictable as a limit of predictable processes. I have understood why $A_{mn}(t)$ is predictable but the second part regarding $A_{m}(t)\rightarrow A$ for $m\rightarrow\infty$ seems non trivial and it is not explained thoroughly.

How does this convergence occur?

Comment: @TheBridge Yes. $F$ is the c.d.f. of $T$. $T$ is the failure time.  There are no other information for $F$.